# Invoice email not received while place order in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, frontend, invoice

I have not received invoice email after placing order.

Magento version : **2.2.2 & 2.3.0**

Checked in these Payment Methods : **Authorize.net & Zero subtotal Checkout**

**Expected result:**

1. Order Created
2. Email with order information send.
3. Invoice Created
4. Email with invoice information send

**Actual Result**

Order Created <- working

Email with order information send. <- working

Invoice Created <- working

Email with invoice information is not send <- not working.

For Zero subtotal Checkout payment method settings follow below steps:

**Enable zero subtotal checkout.**

1. Set new order status to processing.
2. Create a cart rule with 100% rebate and free shipping.
3. Place order with coupon code & free shipping method.
4. Check order detail in admin Invoice was generated but email not received.

From back-end when send email button clicked manually in Invoice view page - proper email invoice received.

**Same issue happen will Authorize.net Direct Post payment method,**

set Payment action as **Authorize & Capture**,

new Order status as **Processing** ,

so while place an order with authorize.net

> > order placed successfully
> >
> > order email was also received
> >
> > Invoice generated properly
> >
> > but invoice email not received.

If anyone have any idea please let me know.

Thanks in Advance..!!!

Comment: In magento for Zero subtotal Checkout, in order to send the mail once invoice are generated you need to trigger it manually.

Comment: @aravind, okay and what about Authorize.net Direct Post payment method invoice email issue ?

Comment: what is the option you have set in  "Payment action" field in backend? It should be "Authorize and Capture"

Comment: Yes Payment action set as "Authorize and Capture" and also New Order Status set as "Processing".